# Error message when I try adblocker build

Tags: python, firefox-addon, adblock

I am trying to build adblockplus from [this link](http://adblockplus.org/downloads/adblockplus-2.0.3-source.tgz). When I issue the command:

```
python build.py build
```

I end up getting the following error message. I tried with and without sudo to no avail.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 10, in <module>
    buildtools.build.processArgs('.', sys.argv)
  File "/home/machine/projects/weird/buildtools/build.py", line 352, in processArgs
    commands[command](baseDir, scriptName, opts, args, type)
  File "/home/machine/projects/weird/buildtools/build.py", line 39, in __call__
    return self._handler(baseDir, scriptName, opts, args, type)
  File "/home/machine/projects/weird/buildtools/build.py", line 166, in runBuild
    limitMetadata=limitMetadata)
  File "/home/machine/projects/weird/buildtools/packager.py", line 274, in createBuild
    buildNum = getBuildNum(baseDir)
  File "/home/machine/projects/weird/buildtools/packager.py", line 80, in getBuildNum
    (result, dummy) = subprocess.Popen(['hg', 'id', '-n'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Am I missing a package? Any hint on what the problem could be will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The stack trace makes it clear that the issue is caused by the following line:

```
(result, dummy) = subprocess.Popen(['hg', 'id', '-n'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

If you look at the [`subprocess` package documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), this line is trying to run the `hg id -n` command (get numerical Mercurial revision). Apparently, the Mercurial command line tool isn't present on your system (a possibility  that this build script didn't consider) so it fails.

*Disclaimer*: I happen to be the one who wrote this script and I [fixed this bug](https://hg.adblockplus.org/buildtools/rev/de073dd6cc00) now. Mercurial isn't essential for the build, the revision number is pretty much only necessary to determine the output file name.

Comment: Wladimir, thanks and this put me back on track on the forgotten project that I was working on. I will try again.